# Dell XPS KVM Switch on Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I'm trying to use a KVM switch with my Dell XPS (and a macbook pro).

The KVM switch is a Thunderbolt 4 switch. It works very nicely with the macbook, it also works very nicely with another linux "nuc" style computer that I have. It only misbehaves with the dell + linux.

The problem is the monitors will never reconnect to the dell laptop after switching off and switching back. If I boot the dell laptop while connected to the kvm switch it works just fine, but after switching away and back the monitors never come back. When I open the laptop I can see the thunderbolt dock is connected, all other peripherals work, its just the monitors are never re-detected.

My theory is this is related to how dell handles the laptop built-in screen. When booting from scratch with monitors connected the laptop screen is correctly disabled. It does not appear in the list of available displays. But after switching off the kvm switch the laptop screen gets turned on (I can actually see it light up under my closed laptop lid) and after this happens the built in laptop screen never goes away and the laptop stops detecting any other connected monitor no matter how many times I reconnect it.

I am 90% confident its something related to that built in screen (which is not an issue on the nuc linux machine which works fine). But I don't understand why it seems to lock up and stop detecting reconnected displays. Feels like an issue at the bios level that I will not be able to solve, but posting here anyway. Dell XPS is a popular laptop, has anyone else had this issue with KVM switching?

I've also just in generally hated this behaviour when using the dell laptop standalone. I always disable the "lid switch" to prevent it from sleeping when I close the lid, but then the dell laptop just leaves the display on with the lid closed -_- which is not cool.

I wish the dell would physically disable the built-in display when the lid was closed, then I imagine the KVM switch would also work (like it does on the nuc). Is there a way I can make this happen?

Comment: You should add that critical information in the question body instead of a comment.

Comment: I had issues with displays behind Thunderbolt as well. Seems to be buggy as display detection was a matter of luck in the early days of EDID. In my case a firmware update of the Thunderbolt controller and the BIOS of the notebook fixed it.

Comment: Goofing around for another couple hours tonight. Updated firmware which helped windows work more smoothly. My only issue is with linux where it fails 80% of the time, but works perfectly the other 20% of the time. Sometimes I could even get it to work repeatedly several times in a row before failing unexpectedly. Resetting the power supply on the hub fixed it one time, but never again (otherwise I would have taken that as a workaround). My guess is an unstable kernel, gonna try an old LTS when I get time, and I'll try the new Ubuntu LTS when it comes out in April :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem with a workaround.

By using a powered thunderbolt4/usb4 hub between the KVM switch and the dell laptop.

So my setup is something like:

```
[Macbook] <-- [TB4 KVM Switch] --> [TB4 Hub] --> [Dell Ubuntu Laptop]
```

I think this is something to do with negotiation of Power Delivery on the Dell hardware; possibly also combined with the negotiation of the built-in display on the Dell hardware. When the KVM switch reconnected it felt like it took a long time for the Dell to re-negotiate what was happening (and then it ultimately failed to detect displays).

By using the powered thunderbolt4 hub between the switch and the dell, the dell never needs to re-negotiate power-delivery while the KVM is switching. The dell sees a consistent connection to a hub and that must be enough to help the rest of the connection process succeed.

I tried to eliminate the power delivery negotiation issue by using a dedicated charger (usb-c wall-wart with more power than the laptop needed), but that apparently was not enough to fix the issue (this XPS-13 does not have a dedicated DC power port, only usb-c power).

It now works perfectly with this powered hub workaround. When the kvm switch is on with the lid closed the built in display is correctly disabled. Switching the KVM off/on causes the built in display to re-enable/disable appropriately and the external monitors are detected and come on correctly.

It's not even that inconvenient. It gives me the added bonus of consistent charging for the dell. It's the same number of wires to plug into the dell. It's just an extra thing next to the KVM switch but it doesn't get in the way.

I will update if I get any other major revelations, but I don't think I'll be able to do much better than this so I'm considering it mostly "solved" for now.